# Can't pass var between functions in JS Codepen with Geolocations API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-geolocation

I am having trouble with passing a url variable between functions in my JS code on CodePen:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  var lat = crd.latitude;
  var long = crd.longitude;
  var JSONurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + long + "&key=MY_APIKEY";

  console.log(JSONurl);
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  return JSONurl;
 };

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
};

function getCity() {

  $.getJSON( JSONurl, function( json ) {
  var arr = $.map(json, function(el) { return el; })

  // console.log(Object.keys(arr[3]));
  console.log(arr[3]["address_components"][1]["long_name"]);

  }
)};


var JSONurl = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);             
getCity(JSONurl);
```

Ideally I would like to just call the `getCity()` function and for that function to call the `success(pos)` function and for that to initiate and return the JSONurl variable to `getCity()`.

I have no idea why this doesn't work, but it's a bit hack-ey anyway so any suggestions for improvements welcome.

Comment: I think function getCity() should be function getCity(JSONurl)

Comment: Ok , but if I replace last line with:var JSONurl = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
console.log(JSONurl);
getCity(JSONurl); that still doesn't log JSONurl to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So there are a couple of issues:
>
> 1. navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options) does not return a value. So "return JSONurl" will never work.
> 2. key=MY_APIKEY should be your googleapis key (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key, if not already)
> 3. You need to use a promise because you don't know when the googleapis will return the info.
> 4. You're probably going to have to use a callback function due to reason above.
> 5. You need to take into account if the API denies the request.

[Working verison jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PantsStatusZero/ee60mLpb/2/) - will prompt for google api key

```
(function(window){

  // Declare internal variables
  var _jsonURL = "";
  var _coords =  "";
  var _latitude =  "";
  var _longitude =  "";

  // Enter your google api key when prompted
  // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
  var APIKEY = prompt("Please enter your google API key ", ""); ; 

  // Create promise
  var _def = $.Deferred();

  window.GoogleAPI = {      
     options : {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 5000,
                maximumAge: 0
     },
     getGeolocation : function(){
                // Set deferred action
                _def = $.Deferred(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, GoogleAPI.options));

                // allows chaining
                return this;
     },
     getCity : function(callback){
        _def.done(function(){
            var city = "";

            $.getJSON( _jsonURL, function( json ) {
               //check if access to the API was denied
               if (json.status == "REQUEST_DENIED"){
                        console.error("API access denied.")
                        callback(null);
                        return;
                    };

               var arr = $.map(json, function(el) { return el; })

               city = arr[3]["address_components"][0]["long_name"];
               console.log(city);

               callback(city);
            })
            .fail(function(){
               console.warn("failed to getCity");              
               callback(null);
            }); //end getJSON          
         }); //end _def

         // allows chaining
         return this;
     } //end getCity
 }; //end window.GoogleAPI 



  function success(pos) {
     _coords = pos.coords;
     _latitude = _coords.latitude;
     _longitude = _coords.longitude;
     _jsonURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + _latitude  + "," + _longitude + "&key=" + APIKEY; 

     console.log(_jsonURL);
     console.log(`Latitude : ${_coords.latitude}`);
     console.log(`Longitude: ${_coords.longitude}`);

     // Tell the promise the deferred action has been completed
     _def.resolve();
  };

  function error(err) {
     console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);

     // Tell the promise the deferred action has failed
     _def.reject();
  };

}(window))

GoogleAPI.getGeolocation()
         .getCity(function(data){
             if(data){
                // do something with the data
                 alert(data);
             }
         });
```

**Notes on Promises:**

Promises/deferred function is a heavy subject. Technically, $.getJSON is a promise that's assumed successful (although they included .fail() for error handling.)

```
var _def = $.Deferred(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, GoogleAPI.options)); <-- create a deferred action (a promise.)
```

Promises are async functions. Normally used when there is delay in getting data.

```
_def.resolve(); <-- Says the promised action took place. 
_def.reject(); <-- Says the promised action failed.
_def.done(function(){}) <-- runs if promised action was successful. 
_def.fail(function(){}) <-- runs id promised action failed.
```

Comment: Yep I know about API keys, I just wondered about security and, even tho google gives them out for free I work in Cyber Security I thought there must be a reason there is a key so I didn't want to put mine in the code!

Comment: That makes sense. Where you able to get the rest of it to work?  Google's geolocation api seems very unforgiving. lol

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm having trouble understanding some of this: 1) I don't get why the navigator.geolocation etc function needs to be deferred? Am I not understanding something about callbacks? Why is it 'return this' and not 'return _def '? 2) What is window.GoogleAPI ? Is it mimicking class behaviour with js by making a function of functions? 3) Which bit is the promise and what is happening with that?

Comment: I am going to answer these in sections. GoogleAPI is a random variable being used to extend the window object. This is done to namespace and it would be possible rewrite this to work like a normal class. Right now it works like a singleton (static class.)

Comment: Why is it 'return this' and not 'return _def'? 'return this' returns to the GoogleAPI object which has functions called getGeolocation and getCity. 'return _def' would return the promise.

Comment: why does navigator.geolocation etc function needs to be deferred? It doesn't if you want to execute all your code out of the success function, but there are limitations to that. And because the getCity is outside the success 
 function, something as to check to make sure that function ran first.